# How to unwind shorted youtube video link

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, youtube

**I'm trying to unwind any sort of shorted link of youtube video.
Link ex: [http://y2u.be/j4dMnAPZu70, https://rb.gy/22z4p] ect.**

**This is the code I try to get video link, but it's not working the way I thought it would**

*Is any way to get youtube original link from shorted link*

```js
const urls = ["http://y2u.be/j4dMnAPZu70", "https://rb.gy/22z4p"];


const extractVideoId = async url => {
  const videoIdRegex =
    /^(?:(?:https?:)?\/\/)?(?:(?:www|m)\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com\/(?:embed\/|v\/|watch(?:\?v=|\/(?=v))|(?=.*\bvi?=))|youtu\.be\/|youtu\.com\/(?:embed\/|v\/|watch(?:\?v=|\/(?=v))|(?=.*\bvi?=)))((\w|-){11})(?=[^\w-]|$)(?![?=&+%\w.-]*(?:['"][^<>]*>|<\/a>))[?=&+%\w.-]*$/
  const match = url.match(videoIdRegex)

  if (match) {
    return match[1]
  } else {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(url, {
        maxRedirects: 0,
        validateStatus: status => status >= 200 && status < 300
      })
      console.log(response)
      const redirectUrl = response.headers.location
      if (!redirectUrl) {
        return null
      }

      const videoId = redirectUrl.match(/v=([^&]+)/)
      if (videoId) {
        return videoId[1]
      } else {
        return null
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
      return null
    }
  }
};
urls.forEach(url => console.log(extractVideoId(url)))
```